# Custom useForm typescript not working properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx

Below is my `useForm` hook:

```
const useForm = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const inputHandler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    e.persist();
    setState((preState) => ({
      ...preState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  return [state, inputHandler];
};
export default useForm;
```

Then in tsx file I have code:

```
const [state, inputHandler] = useForm();
...
    <input
          name="title"
          type="text"
          value={"title" in state ? state.title : ""}
          onChange={inputHandler} // error!!!
          placeholder="Title"
          className="mb-2 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 block w-full pr-12 sm:text-sm border-red-300 rounded-md"
        />
```

but the `onChange` always complain Type `{}` is not assignable to type `ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>`. I've change the `{}` to `Any` but it seems the inputHandler always return init state not event handler function I defined in the custom hook.

Comment: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-typeing-custom-hooks/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the error is caused by the return array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours investigation, I found the error is caused by the return []. I replace it with return {...}. The hook works like a charm